# Simple looking diophantine equation...

Tags: diophantine-equations

I recently found myself asking if the following (diophantine) expression ever evaluates to a square number:

$$5+12n$$

I was surprised both to be unable to stumble across an integer value for $n$ that results in a square number, and then surprised not see an obvious, eloquent, proof showing why this expression can never be square.

I would be interested in any pointers to work on the question of if/when equations of the form:

$$ A + Bn = c^2 $$

have a (non-trivial) solution.  I'm assuming the convention that capital variables are constants, while non-capitals are free variables.

Comment: For fixed $B$ this is straightforward: once you know that multiplication respects remainders $\bmod B$, you only have to check whether there is a solution with $c = 0, 1, 2, ... N-1$ to check whether there is any solution.

Answer (score 4):

Look modulo $B$:
$$
A\equiv c^2\text{ (mod }B\text{)}
$$
I don't know whether or not you're familiar with [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity), but there is plenty of information on that Wikipedia article about conditions for $A$ to be a square modulo $B$ if $B$ is an odd prime. If there is no solution modulo $B$, then there is no solution in general.

In your specific case, $5$ is not a square modulo $12$ (you can easily check that squaring the numbers $1$ to $11$, and then finding their remainder when divided by $12$ will never give you $5$), so there is no solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Quadratic Reciprocity looks very relevant – was/am not (properly) familiar. :)  While I can accept that there is no solution for 5+12x=y^2 I would still like to know why I can be sure that checking up-to 11 is sufficient.  Why, for different constants, couldn't there be a solution where c>B despite no solution for c<B?

Comment: @aSteve If there exists an integer $c$ such that $c^2=A+Bn$, then $c^2\equiv A$ (mod $B$). If you take the contrapositive of that statement, then $c^2\equiv A$ (mod $B$) having no solutions implies that $c^2=A+Bn$ has no solutions. It's not about whether or not it has a solution $<B$, it's about whether or not it has a solution modulo $B$ (there is a difference!). There are only $B$ integers modulo $B$ (every integer, when divided by $B$, will leave a remainder $0\le r\le B-1$), so that's why you only check up to $B-1$.

Comment: I suspect I should read a text-book on modular arithmetic. (Recommendations welcome...) I can accept that it is sufficient to check up to B-1 (as values for c) but I still can't picture this justification for myself.

Comment: @aSteve Suppose that the integers $A+Bn$ and $c^2$ are equal. Then when you divide them by **ANY** integer, they leave the same remainder. That's what you're doing when you consider the equation modulo $B$. You're saying that if $A+Bn=c^2$, then $A+Bn$ and $c^2$ leave the same remainder when you divide by $B$. Since $Bn$ is perfectly divisible by $B$ with no remainder, we know that $A$ and $c^2$ must leave the same remainder when divided by $B$, i.e. $A\equiv c^2$ (mod $B$). If you can't find a solution modulo $B$ (checking up to $B-1$), then you couldn't have had a solution to start with.

Comment: I feel as if I'm "being difficult" - you eloquently explain those aspects of the problem I'm happy with... yet I can't reciprocate (pun) with a concise explanation of the potential problem... partly because I don't think a counter example exists.  Essentially, the LHS looks "linear" - while the RHS is "more" "non-linear" - and that feels relevant.  What if I replaced c^2 with f(c) - and define f(c)=A when c=13B and 0 otherwise?  I can see that your approach worked, but I'm less clear about why it "must work", and the limits to which this technique can be stretched.

Comment: @aSteve You're not being difficult at all! This method works for any polynomial (linear or not) with integer coefficients. The $f$ that you've concocted there isn't a polynomial. You can rewrite $5+12n=c^2$ as $f(x,y)=5+12x-y^2$ for example. If you really want to see a limitation, consider $g(x)=(x^2-2)(x^2-17)(x^2-34)$. This polynomial has solutions modulo $n$ for *all* n, but has no integer solutions in general. So in a sense, this method doesn't tell you anything about $g(x)$. This method will only help you decide if an equation *doesn't* have solutions, it won't work the other way around!

Comment: Ta again... 'any polynomial' makes sense to me.  Your g(x) looks curious - though it raises questions orthogonal to what I was originally interested in.  My instinct makes it hard for me to accept that knowledge about an equation modulo-N tells you "nothing" about it 'in general' - though I do recognise that any relationship might be perilously complicated.

Comment: @aSteve Certain polynomials have integral solutions if and only if they have real solutions in $\mathbb{R}$, and solutions modulo $p^n$ for every prime $p$ and every $n>0$. Such polynomials are said to satisfy the [Hasse principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle). It is a natural question to ask when you can piece together modular solutions (*local* solutions) to give you an integer solution (*global* solution), but as you have quite rightly said yourself, the relationship is in general quite complicated! I do feel that I've digressed from your original point, so I do apologise.

Comment: @aSteve Also, you might find [this link](http://www.mathdb.org/notes_download/elementary/number/ne_N3.pdf) useful. It talks through some of the basic ideas behind trying to solve Diophantine equations, including examples using modular arithmetic and quadratic residues to prove no solutions exist.

Comment: Ta again... lots of reading for me to do.  This might take some time. :)  The www.mathdb.org site looks as if it might be generally useful - if only I could read Chinese (I assume).